# Send a value from view file to widget in yii

Tags: php, view, yii, widget

I have a blog, in which there are different blog types, each blog type have many number of blog posts. I am passing the ID of blog type to get the detail of the blog post (a foreign key relation ship). For the sidebar I have created a widget, I would like to pass the blogtype ID to the widget so that I can show the latest posts of the corresponding blog type.

I have tried this in the view file

```
 $this->widget('application.widget.blogs',array(blog_type_id=>$res_blog));
```

this in the widget

```
 class Categories extends CWidget
 {
 public $blog_type;
 public function run() 
 {
   echo $blog_type;
 }
 }
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Can any one please look into the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep widgets on `Components/Blogs.php` and create code like below .

```
class Blogs extends CWidget
{
   public $blog_type_id;
   public function run() 
   {
   echo $this->blog_type_id; 
   // put other relevant code here. 
   }
}
```

And, you can call this with,

```
$this->widget('blogs',array(blog_type_id=>$res_blog));
```

If you put above class code inside as  **protected/widget/Blogs.php** then you can call this widget like,

```
 $this->widget('application.widget.blogs',array(blog_type_id=>$res_blog));
```

Answer (score 2):

How to do this? My example...

Folder Structure:

```
        Application (Your App Folder)
            |
            |
            protected (Folder)
                |
                |
                widget (Folder)
                    |
                    |
                    views (Folder)
                    |    |
                    |    blog.php (PHP View file)
                    |
                    Blog.php (PHP Class file)
```

**Blog.php** under protected/widget/

```
        <?php
        class Blog extends CWidget
        {
            public $dataProvider;
            public function init()
            {
                // this method is called by CController::beginWidget()
            }

            public function run()
            {
                $dataSet=$this->dataProvider->getData();
                $this->render('blog', array('dataSet'=>$dataSet));
            }
        }
        ?>
```

**blog.php** under protected/widget/views/

```
        <!-- Your View as you want. Example: -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Blog Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($dataSet as $data): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $data->name; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $data->description; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
```

How to Use this widget

```
        <?php
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('YourBlogModel'); //It has to come from controller
        $this->widget('application.widget.Blog', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider)); 
        ?>
```